# Numpy error: shape mismatch

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I was trying to solve a scientific problem with Python (Numpy), a 'shape mismatch' error came up: "shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape". I managed to reproduce the same error in a simpler form, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
nx = 3; ny = 5
ff = np.ones([nx,ny,7])
def test(x, y):
    z = 0.0
    for i in range(7):
        z = z + ff[x,y,i]
    return z

print test(np.arange(nx),np.arange(ny))
```

When I tried to call `test(x,y)` with `x=1,y=np.arange(ny)`, everything works fine. So what's going on here? Why can't the both parameters be numpy arrays?

*UPDATE*

I have worked out the problem with some hints from @Saullo Castro. Here's some updated info for you guys who tried to help but feel unclear about my intention:

Basically I created a mesh grid with dimension nx*ny and another array `ff` that stores some value for each node. In the above code, `ff` has 7 values for each node and I was trying to sum up the 7 values to get a new nx*ny array.

However, the "shape mismatch" error is not due to the summing process as many of you might have guess now. I have misunderstood the rule of functions taking ndarray objects as input parameters. I tried to pass `np.arange(nx), np.arange(ny)` to `test()` is not gonna give me what I desired, even if `nx==ny`.

Back to my original intention, I solve the problem by creating another function and used `np.fromfunction` to created the array:

```
def tt(x, y):  
    return np.fromfunction(lambda a,b: test(a,b), (x, y))
```

which is not perfect but it works. (In this example there seems to be no need to create a new function, but in my actual code I modified it a bit so it can be used for slice of the grid)

Anyway, I do believe there's a much better way compared to my kind of dirty solution. So if you have any idea about that, please share with us :).

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how indexing multi-dimensional arrays works, have a look at the docs; it is very clear explanation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: @Akavall Could you be more specific about that? BTW I'm aware that I'm mixing the `x[i]` and `i` since they are the same in this simplified case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look into an array similar to your `ff` array:

```
nx = 3; ny = 4
ff = np.arange(nx*ny*5).reshape(nx,ny,5)
#array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],
#
#       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
#        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
#        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
#        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],
#
#       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
#        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
#        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
#        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

When you index using arrays of indices `a, b, c` like in `ff[a, b, c]`, `a, b, c` must have the same shape, and `numpy` will build a new array based on the indices. For example:

```
ff[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
#array([ 0,  5, 20, 26, 51, 56])
```

This is called fancy indexing, which is like building an array with:

```
np.array([ff[0, 0, 0], ff[0, 1, 0], ff[1, 0, 0], ..., ff[2, 3, 1]])
```

In your case the `f[x, y, i]` will produce a shape mismatch error since `a, b, c` do not have the same shape.

Comment: Thank you Saullo Castro. I have updated my original post. Please take a look.

Comment: @seekiu I read you update, you could probably achieve the same result with `ff.sum(axis=2)`...

Comment: @seekiu you showld consider accepting one of the answers if they fit your needs...

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer since I worked out my problem based on it, even though not exactly what I was asking for. Pity I cannot vote others' useful because my reputation is too low... Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to sum `ff` over the last dimension, with the 1st 2 dimensions covering their whole range.  `:` is used to denote the whole range of a dimension:

```
def test():
    z = 0.0
    for i in range(7):
        z = z + ff[:,:,i]
    return z
print test()
```

But you can get the same result without looping, by using the `sum` method.

```
print ff.sum(axis=-1)
```

`:` is shorthand for `0:n`

```
ff[0:nx, 0:ny, 0]==ff[:,:,0]
```

It is possible to index a block of `ff` with ranges, but you have to be much more careful about the shapes of the indexing arrays.  For a beginner it is better to focus on getting `slicing` and `broadcasting` correct.

---

edit -

You can index an array like `ff` with arrays generated by `meshgrid`:

```
I,J = meshgrid(np.arange(nx),np.arange(ny),indexing='ij',sparse=False)
I.shape # (nx,ny)
ff[I,J,:]
```

also works with

```
I,J = meshgrid(np.arange(nx),np.arange(ny),indexing='ij',sparse=True)
I.shape # (nx,1)
J.shape # (1, ny)
```

`ogrid` and `mgrid` are alternatives to `meshgrid`.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj. I have updated my original post. Please take a look.

Comment: I wonder if the kinds of grids produced by `meshgrid` are useful in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Let's reproduce your problem in 2D case, so it is easier to see:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)

x = np.arange(3)
y = np.arange(5)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> a[x, y] # <- This is the error that you are getting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

# You are getting the error because x and y are different lengths,
# If x and y were the same lengths, the code would work: 

>>> a[x, x]
array([ 0,  6, 12])

# mixing arrays and scalars is not a problem

>>> a[x, 2]
array([ 2,  7, 12])
```

Comment: Thank you Akavall. I have updated my original post. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in your question what you are trying to do or what result are you expecting. It seems, though, that you are trying to calculate a total with your variable `z`.

Check if the `sum` method produces the result that you need:

```
import numpy as np
nx = 3; ny = 5

ff = ff = np.array(np.arange(nx*ny*7)).reshape(nx,ny,7)

print ff.sum()          # 5460

print ff.sum(axis=0)    # array([[105, 108, 111, 114, 117, 120, 123],
                        #        [126, 129, 132, 135, 138, 141, 144],
                        #        [147, 150, 153, 156, 159, 162, 165],
                        #        [168, 171, 174, 177, 180, 183, 186],
                        #        [189, 192, 195, 198, 201, 204, 207]]) shape(5,7)

print ff.sum(axis=1)    # array([[ 70,  75,  80,  85,  90,  95, 100],
                        #        [245, 250, 255, 260, 265, 270, 275],
                        #        [420, 425, 430, 435, 440, 445, 450]]) shape (3,7)

print ff.sum(axis=2)    # array([[ 21,  70, 119, 168, 217],
                        #        [266, 315, 364, 413, 462],
                        #        [511, 560, 609, 658, 707]]) shape (3,5)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my original post. Please take a look.